# System update is stuck on: "The update package has been deleted..."

Tags: macos, software-update

Updates to macOS repeatedly fail with this error:

[image]

The text reads:

> The update package has been
> deleted since being downloaded
> from the Apple Software Update
> server.

I don't know what would be deleting the update package, as the error states. It feels as though the downloaded package is corrupted somehow, but the update doesn't know how to clear the cache and start over.

How do I clear update-related caches, or what do I need to do to clear this broken state and get the system update to work again? Restarting doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

It appears macOS is retrieving updates from a caching server that has run out of disk space.

If you are running the caching server locally, or you can find who is running it on your network (possibly your network administrator),

- give it more disk space by increasing its quota in System Settings → General → Sharing → Content Caching → Options

  [image]

  and ensuring the volume has sufficient free space
- disable it [per sog's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/450418/37797).

Answer (score 0):

You need to **disable** Content Sharing in System Preferences>Sharing.

Restart your Mac and after that try downloading the updates again.